# Xcode stuck with loading wheel after adding Apple Watch Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I have recently added an Apple Watch App and Extension to my app. Since then my Xcode regularly (every 2-3minutes) freezes with the colored loading indicaton for about 10 seconds.

This is extremely annoying and I cannot find any indication as to why it is happening. It just gets stuck when looking at source code or scrolling.

Did anyone experience a similar issues after integrating Apple Watch and knows how to solve this? I have a feeling it could be related to trying to connect to the Apple Watch, as I have setup wireless debugging for my phone.

Comment: I’ve found on-device Apple Watch debugging to always be very unreliable unfortunately. I only use the simulator now because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is just an expected behavior when doing wireless debugging with an Apple Watch. Developing for watchOS can be fun, but you’ll have to pack a good amount of patience. In my own experience I’ve had to deal with randomly cut off connections, Xcode freezing, and all sorts of instability. You may have better luck with the watchOS simulator, if it can satisfy your use case.